# How to manipulate a wpf object using input value

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

please help me to learn,,

I make a WPF object in Expression Blend and make it's storyboard,,then I import that object to Visual C# WinForm...
My question is how to control the object storyboard timing using Visual C# WinForm,,
Ex. If I input value = 20 then the object storyboard will move from 0 to 20 seconds..
Or is there any other method to control the object??

Please show me a way...

Comment: Do you even know what WinForms is i wonder?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need to modify your Storyboard from code-behind.
You have two options:

- Bind your storyboard properties to something that you can modify from code (for example a CLR Property)

  http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tamir/archive/2007/03/19/How-to-bind-to-Animation-To-and-FROM-properties.aspx
- name your storyboard and change it directly from code

  http://www.galasoft-lb.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2006102701.aspx